# CNTK Learner and zipped arguments in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, cntk

I've been following the CNTK Tutorial [CNTK 203: Reinforcement Learning Basics](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tutorials/CNTK_203_Reinforcement_Learning_Basics.ipynb) and encountered sending the arguments to the Learner in the Brain class in the following way:

```
 arguments = dict(zip(self.loss.arguments, [x,y]))
 updated, results =self.trainer.train_minibatch(arguments, outputs=[self.loss.output])
```

This is the first time this is done in the tutorials. Can anyone understand why the arguments are a dictionary of zip objects? What does zip do in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zip is a builtin function in python that creates tuples out of its list arguments. See [this](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) for more details. The code in question just createes a dictionary mapping the input variables of the network to the values x and y.